# Prove that one hypothesis is negation of another in Coq

Tags: coq, proof

For example I have these two hypotheses (one is negation of other)

```
H : forall e : R, e > 0 -> exists p : X, B e x p -> ~ F p
H0 : exists e : R, e > 0 -> forall p : X, B e x p -> F p
```

And goal

```
False
```

How to prove it?

Comment: What if the `e` the assumption `H0` says exist is negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, because `H0` is not the negation of `H`. The correct statement would be

```
Definition R := nat.
Parameter X: Type.
Parameter T: Type.
Parameter x: T.
Parameter B : R -> T -> X -> Prop.
Parameter F : X -> Prop.

Lemma foobar: forall (H: forall e : R, e > 0 -> exists p : X, B e x p -> ~ F p)
  (H0:  exists e: R, e > 0 /\ forall p: X, B e x p /\ F p), False.
Proof.
intros H H0.
destruct H0 as [e [he hforall]].
destruct (H e he) as [p hp].
destruct (hforall p) as [hB hF].
exact (hp hB hF).
Qed.
```